# Mouse occasionally stops responding

Tags: 11.10

I installed Ubuntu 11.10 on my Sony Vaio a month ago.  Since then everything was ok but recently my mouse stops responding occasionally.

What could be the problem and how would I fix it?

Comment: That happens to me as well. Check out relevant bug report at redhat: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=734287 - Check out `dmesg | grep mouse` output, I get "psmouse.c: bad data from KBC - timeout"

Answer (score 0):

I can get the mouse working again by opening a terminal and running `sudo rmmod psmouse && sudo modprobe psmouse`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes my **USB mouse** get stuck too, but I realized that it occours when I accidentally hit the touchpad, activating some eternal Drag & (don't) Drop.

So here is a "quick dirty fix" that always works for me: just hit the touchpad again or the touchpad left button. Then, your USB mouse will get unstuck :)

You could wan't to disable the touchpad also, if you use the USB mouse more often.